# Drag and drop from Collectionview into ContactViewController doesn't work on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, drag-and-drop

I'm developing an app which uses **splitView**.

I'm using two items in **splitView** (Called them **Customer** and **Supplier**).

When I click on one of them I just use one **viewController** to display (called it: **ContactViewController**) and I use **collectionView** to display its data. To get data I just code it:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (!dbManager.synchronized) {
        if (contactType == ContactTypeCustomer)
            [dbManager requestData:kDbCustomers predicate:nil target:self];
        else if (contactType == ContactTypeSuppplier)
            [dbManager requestData:kDbSuppliers predicate:nil target:self];
    }
}
```

And when get successful:

```
#pragma mark
#pragma DBDelegate

- (void)requestDataCompleted:(NSMutableArray *)results
{
    datasource = results;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

I use **I3DragBetweenHelper** downloaded from [github.com](https://github.com/ice3-software/i3-dragndrop)

Embedded into my app to initial drag and drop. To do this, I call the below method into **viewDidLoad** of **ContactViewController**

```
- (void) initDragAndDrop
{
    self.helper = [[I3DragBetweenHelper alloc] initWithSuperview:self.view
                                                         srcView:_collectionView
                                                         dstView:_collectionView];
    self.helper.delegate = self;
    self.helper.isDstRearrangeable = NO;
    self.helper.isSrcRearrangeable = NO;
    self.helper.doesSrcRecieveDst = NO;
    self.helper.doesDstRecieveSrc = YES;
    self.helper.hideDstDraggingCell = YES;
    self.helper.hideSrcDraggingCell = NO;
}
```

The **helper** here is:
`@property (strong, nonatomic) I3DragBetweenHelper *helper;`

The problem is when I click on **Supplier** I **can** drag and drop the cell of **collectionView** into **ContactViewController**. Below method had called and worked:
`- (BOOL)droppedOutsideAtPoint:(CGPoint)pointIn fromDstIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)from`

But when I click on **Customer** the above method doesn't call. I can't even drag my cell of **collectionView** into **ContactViewController**. Any help will appreciate.

Comment: Not working in iPad ..it's mean your app is working in other iOS devices ?

Comment: Another person edit my question title.My app for iPad and it's work but not all. Please read my question.

Answer (score 0):

Why is `isDstRearrangeable` set to `NO` ??? coz eventually you would grab something and drop it onto something ( dest ) and that something ( dest ) will be rearranged, am i wrong ??

does your drag and drop happen in the same place ?? ( i.e: `UICollectionView` )

if it does, then why do you have src as not rearrangeable ??? both your destination and src should be rearrangeable.

Try this and let me know how it goes :)

Comment: +I try to change `isDstRearrangeable` to `YES`, but it's not work too. +When I drag a **cell** out of **collectionView** this cell will be delete and the **collectionView** will reload **cell** and data.I use the same **viewcontroller** to display data into **collectionView**

Comment: But the drag and drop just work when this **viewController** set as Supplier. Did not know why data set as Customer and then can not drag.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about this library but I think the problem is your srcView and dstView are the same.  These should be different and must be either UITableView or UICollectionView.

If you are using UISplitViewController, its probably going to be the Master and Detail View Controllers used by the UISplitView

Comment: No, it's not the problem. Because it's worked in Supplier as I written above.